# Filtering records in one table based on records in other table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have two data.table dt and dt1 which looks like:

```
> dt <- data.table(grp = c("A", "A",  "B", "B", "C"),
                   cat = c("01", "02", "01", "02", "01"),
                  Value = c(234, 234, 235, 536, 235))

> dt
   grp cat Value
1:   A  01   234
2:   A  02   234
3:   B  01   235
4:   B  02   536
5:   C  01   235

> dt1 <- data.table(grp = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B", "B","C"),
                   cat = c("01","01","02","02","03","04", "01","01", "02", "03","01"),
                   rec = c(5435,4341, 32525,436,7087,467,523,245,568,24,789),
                   val = c(346,6876,436,6807,465,65875,6432,754,326532,746,578))

> dt1
    grp cat   rec    val
 1:   A  01  5435    346
 2:   A  01  4341   6876
 3:   A  02 32525    436
 4:   A  02   436   6807
 5:   A  03  7087    465
 6:   A  04   467  65875
 7:   B  01   523   6432
 8:   B  01   245    754
 9:   B  02   568 326532
10:   B  03    24    746
11:   C  01   789    578
```

I want to remove records from table `dt1` for which I don't have corresponding `cat` and `grp` in `dt`.

For example for `grp` A , I don't have records associated with `cat` 03 and 04 in dt. so I want to remove them in dt1.

My final table `dt1` must look like

```
> dt1
    grp cat   rec    val
 1:   A  01  5435    346
 2:   A  01  4341   6876
 3:   A  02 32525    436
 4:   A  02   436   6807
 5:   B  01   523   6432
 6:   B  01   245    754
 7:   B  02   568 326532
 8:   C  01   789    578
```

How can I do this with data.table in R

Comment: `dt1[dt, on = .(grp, cat)]`

Comment: @Jaap changing the comment based on others answer is not good

Comment: @akrun changed the comment before I saw your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
dt1[dt[, -3], on = .(grp, cat)]
#    grp cat   rec    val
#1:   A  01  5435    346
#2:   A  01  4341   6876
#3:   A  02 32525    436
#4:   A  02   436   6807
#5:   B  01   523   6432
#6:   B  01   245    754
#7:   B  02   568 326532
#8:   C  01   789    578
```

Comment: @Jaap If I find a dupe link or related link, I will do it.

Comment: if you find a duplicate, you should close it imo

Comment: @Jaap I don't understand, if you close instead of answer, how are you then supposed to get repz?